# Retrieving one element and filter by another

Tags: xslt, xpath, sorting, distinct

Having tried and failed to modify the XSL from here: [Distinct elements and grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399204/xslt-distinct-elements-and-grouping)

I'm posting here to ask if anyone could please help. I've basically got the same data structure (mine is actually an RSS feed of products) as in the above post, but I want to list the Description elements uniquely, in sorted order where the File element contains a particular value.

I believe the XPath for the File select would be:

```
*/File[text()='file1']
```

for example, to take only the File elements containing the text "file1".

I am unable to work out how to get: "all distinct Description elements sorted, which have a File sibling with value 'file1'".

Any and all help will be very, very much appreciated!

Thanks,

Matt.

Comment: Actually, it's quite good that you have linked to a similar question. This way I can give you a complete solution and you still have some thinking left to do, adapting it to your actual situation. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>

  <!-- index Description elements by their text value -->
  <xsl:key name="kDescription" match="Description" use="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
      <!-- process all Description elements... -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Problems/Problem/Description">
        <!-- ...sorted by their own text value, ascending -->
        <xsl:sort select="text()" />
        <!-- pass in the File value that we want to filter for -->
        <xsl:with-param name="file" select="'file1'" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Description">
    <xsl:param name="file" select="''" />
    <!-- 
      check if the current Description node is the first in its
      respective group, that has a File value we care for
    -->
    <xsl:if test="
      $file != ''
      and
      generate-id()
      =
      generate-id(key('kDescription', .)[../File = $file][1])
    ">
      <!-- for the sake of simplicity, just make a copy here -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<Problems>
  <Problem>
    <File>file1</File>
    <Description>desc1</Description>
  </Problem>
  <Problem>
    <File>file1</File>
    <Description>desc2</Description>
  </Problem>
  <Problem>
    <File>file2</File>
    <Description>desc3</Description>
  </Problem>
  <Problem>
    <File>file2</File>
    <Description>desc1</Description>
  </Problem>
  <Problem>
    <File>file1</File>
    <Description>desc2</Description>
  </Problem>
</Problems>
```

I get:

```
<output>
  <Description>desc1</Description>
  <Description>desc2</Description>
</output>
```

A brief explanation of the part of the stylesheet that does the heavy lifting:

```
$file != ''
and
generate-id()
=
generate-id(key('kDescription', .)[../File = $file][1])
```

The first part is obvious - it's just there to make sure that a `$file` filter string was passed in.

The second part is plain Muenchian grouping with a little twist. It compares the IDs of two nodes, the current one (`generate-id()`) and one from the `kDescription` group, filtered by `$file` value.

`kDescription` indexes `<Description>` elements by their text value, which means that nodes with the same text but a different accompanying `<File>` will be returned by the call to `key()`. We need to filter them out.

If the current node is equal to the first node of the group that has the right `<File>` value, the test succeeds and something gets printed, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your prompt and useful answer. I really have so much to learn here. The XSL key being something that is defying me, also.

Perhaps you could shed light here, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621507/why-dont-all-xslt-templates-get-executed-at-once

Thank you again,

Matt.

Comment: Hi Matt, glad to help. Regarding the xsl:key, I have written something up in my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948218/xslt-3-level-grouping-on-attributes/955527#955527) that might help you understand. Read the lower part of my answer, understanding the question is not necessary in this case. I'm going to have a look at your other question now.

Comment: I see there is an answer there already. Ask if you still require further explanation. :)