# In XSL, do something like in C# : list.Select(x=>x.ID).Distinct();

Tags: c#, xslt, unique, distinct

My intent is in an XSL, to display only once the text node for set of nodes with a common value. For example, I have the following XML:

```
<Nodes>
    <Node att="1">A</Node>
    <Node att="1">B</Node>
    <Node att="2">C</Node>
    <Node att="2">D</Node>
    <Node att="3">E</Node>
</Nodes>
```

My output would be: "ACE".

I don't know what the values of the attribute "att" will be. It can be any string.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's a very similar question, with lots of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399204/xslt-distinct-elements-and-grouping

Comment: The "ACE" output will be for the first one (document order) for each disctinct value. Please do clarify.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for possibly the simplest and shortest solution -- an XPath one-liner. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can even be done just in a single XPath expression**:

```
/*/*[not(@att=preceding-sibling::*/@att)]/text()
```

**So, wrapping it in XSLT gives us**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[not(@att=preceding-sibling::*/@att)]/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and applying this to the provided XML document:**

```
<Nodes>
    <Node att="1">A</Node>
    <Node att="1">B</Node>
    <Node att="2">C</Node>
    <Node att="2">D</Node>
    <Node att="3">E</Node>
</Nodes>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
ACE
```

Comment: I really like your answer, but just to be certain, are the nodes need to be sorted for it to work?

Comment: @Olan: No, no sorting is assumed/needed. The XPath expression selects the first node (in document order) that has a specific, distinct value.

Answer (score 0):

It's a FAQ. See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

This XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="criteria" match="/Nodes/Node" use="@att"/>

<xsl:template match="Nodes">   
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Node[generate-id() = generate-id(key('criteria', @att))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Node">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/> <!-- Or other actions -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will provide the desired (if I understood correctly) output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Nodes>
   <Node att="1">A</Node>
   <Node att="2">C</Node>
   <Node att="3">E</Node>
</Nodes>
```

It would also work with input like, for example:

```
<Nodes>
    <Node att="someRandomString">A</Node>
    <Node att="1aeawe">B</Node>
    <Node att="someRandomString">C</Node>
    <Node att="sfdf">D</Node>
    <Node att="">E</Node>
    <Node att="sfdf">F</Node>
</Nodes>
```

Output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Nodes>
    <Node att="someRandomString">A</Node>
    <Node att="1aeawe">B</Node>
    <Node att="sfdf">D</Node>
    <Node att="">E</Node>
</Nodes>
```

Answer (score 0):

This little stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="kNodeByAtt" match="Node" use="@att"/>
    <xsl:template match="Node[count(.|key('kNodeByAtt',@att)[1])!=1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
ACE
```

**Edit**: Just for fun XPath 2.0 solution

```
string-join((/Nodes/Node)[index-of(/Nodes/Node/@att,@att)[1]],'')
```

Result:

```
ACE
```