# How find distinct data using xpath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Below is my xml

```
<products>
    <product>
        <productid>1001</productid>
        <remarks>
            <title>This is remarks text of 1001</title>
        </remarks>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>1002</productid>
        <remarks>
            <title>This is remarks text of 1002</title>
        </remarks>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>1001</productid>
        <remarks>
            <title>This is remarks text of 1001</title>
        </remarks>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>1001</productid>
        <remarks>
            <title>This is another remarks text of 1001</title>
        </remarks>
    </product>
</products>
```

I need out put like below

1. Take distinct `remarks/title` from there own `productid`
2. need to take out the distinct `remark` of `productid` `1001`

   Productid : 1001
   Remark:This is remarks text of 1001

   Productid : 1001
   Remark:This is another remarks text of 1001

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kProdById" match="product" use="productid"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "product
    [generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kProdById', productid)[1])
    ]
  ">
  <xsl:apply-templates 
     select="key('kProdById', productid)/remarks"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="remarks">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat('Productid : ', ../productid,
           ' Remark:', title, '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <productid>1001</productid>
        <remarks>
            <title>This is remarks text of 1001</title>
        </remarks>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>1002</productid>
        <remarks>
            <title>This is remarks text of 1002</title>
        </remarks>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>1001</productid>
        <remarks>
            <title>This is remarks text of 1001</title>
        </remarks>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>1001</productid>
        <remarks>
            <title>This is another remarks text of 1001</title>
        </remarks>
    </product>
</products>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Productid : 1001 Remark:This is remarks text of 1001
Productid : 1001 Remark:This is remarks text of 1001
Productid : 1001 Remark:This is another remarks text of 1001
Productid : 1002 Remark:This is remarks text of 1002
```

**Explanation**: Using the **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd group the product id and remarks together uniquely using the Muenchean method. There's quite a lot of information on the net about how to do this.

See if this question [xslt-distinct-elements-and-grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399204/distinct-elements-and-grouping) gives you any clues.

Answer (score 0):

with xpath 2.0 we can try like this:

```
distinct-values(/products/product[productid='1001']/remarks/title)
```