# comparing nodes in xml with xslt

Tags: xslt, muenchian-grouping

I am transforming xml data to html page wiith the help of xslt . I want to eliminate duplicate data where appears like this in the following way .

### xml data

```
<calendar>
<event>
<date>May 11</date>
<description>Mother's Day</description>
</event>
<event>
<date>May 12</date>
<description>Birthday</description>
</event>
<event>
<date>May 12</date>
<description>Board Meeting</description>
</event>
</calendar>
```

### My xslt code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Event Dates </h2>
  <table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th>date</th>
  <th>description</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="calendar/event">
  <tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### My output

```
date    description
May 11   Mother's Day
May 12   Birthday
May 12   Board Meeting
```

### Desired Output.

```
date  description
May 11
  Mother's Day

May 12
  Birthday
  Board Meeting
```

Please suggest me the XSLT code to modify .
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399204/xslt-distinct-elements-and-grouping) solution and applied to your problem.
Jenni Tennison wrote a [nice and short explanation](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) of the method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="distinct-date" match="/calendar/event/date" use="./text()"/>
<xsl:template match="calendar">
    <xsl:text>date  description
</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="event/date[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('distinct-date',.)[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//event[date/text() = current()/text()]"/>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="event">
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="description/text()"/>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This short transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:key name="kDateByVal" match="date" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>date  description</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "date[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kDateByVal',.)[1])]">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',.)"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="key('kDateByVal',.)">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;','  ', ../description)"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**uses the classic [Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to transform the provided XML document:**

```
<calendar>
    <event>
        <date>May 11</date>
        <description>Mother's Day</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>May 12</date>
        <description>Birthday</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>May 12</date>
        <description>Board Meeting</description>
    </event>
</calendar>
```

**into the wanted, correct result**:

```
date  description
May 11
  Mother's Day

May 12
  Birthday
  Board Meeting
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve your problem is a so called "Muenchian Grouping". Please refer to
[Muenchian Grouping - group within a node, not within the entire document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753485/muenchian-grouping-group-within-a-node-not-within-the-entire-document) which is pretty much the same as your question, only with names instead of days.